# Which is more efficient coding: reusing variable vs writing same code twice?

Tags: c#, variables, error-handling, coding-style

Let me give you 2 options in coding:

A)

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Error: {0}", genericException.Message));
SomeTextFileLogMethod(String.Format("Error: {0}", genericException.Message));
```

B)

```
var errorMessage = "String.Format("Error: {0}", genericException.Message)";
Console.WriteLine(errorMessage);
SomeTextFileLogMethod(errorMessage);
```

Comment: At this point there's no demonstrable practical angle to work off so this could be flagged for opinion-based and be closed. Realistically what are you going to do with it in the future, over-engineering something is pointless if it's just a mundane feature and wasting more time than necessary on it is a classic example of over-designing

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient"?

Answer (score 0):

It should make intuitive sense that calling `String.Format` twice will incur twice the operational cost. In this demo, you can see the intermediate language generated by code similar to what you are doing. You can see that twice the "work" is done after the `then ...`. The difference is minuscule though. And the compiler can make optimizations that are not obvious so benchmarking is always recommended if there is legitimate concern for performance.

If you really want to code effective logging and messaging I suggest using a library designed for it. Something like Serilog can be configured to write to multiple "sinks". So, one call to log a message could go to the console, and a file, and an email, and an http endpoint, etc., etc.

```
string msg = string.Format("Error: {0}", "test");

Console.WriteLine(msg);
Debug.WriteLine(msg);

Debug.Write("then...");

Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Error: {0}", "test"));
Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Error: {0}", "test"));

IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldstr       "Error: {0}"
IL_0006:  ldstr       "test"
IL_000B:  call        System.String.Format
IL_0010:  stloc.0     // msg
IL_0011:  ldloc.0     // msg
IL_0012:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_0017:  nop         
IL_0018:  ldloc.0     // msg
IL_0019:  call        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine
IL_001E:  nop         
IL_001F:  ldstr       "then..."
IL_0024:  call        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write
IL_0029:  nop         
IL_002A:  ldstr       "Error: {0}"
IL_002F:  ldstr       "test"
IL_0034:  call        System.String.Format
IL_0039:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_003E:  nop         
IL_003F:  ldstr       "Error: {0}"
IL_0044:  ldstr       "test"
IL_0049:  call        System.String.Format
IL_004E:  call        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine
IL_0053:  nop         
IL_0054:  ret
```

Answer (score 0):

`B)` is more "efficient" in terms of maintaining the code since you only define the string once.

It also calls `String.Format` once instead of twice.